# Is it possible to disable/control TFS user (on-premises) to create new Folder under TFS project?

Tags: windows, tfs, version-control

As i know, from user group, part of the access control can be modified
[group access control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQMHG.png)

Also, from each folder under project, specific access control can further be modified
[permission control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxam0.png)

However, both do not have the attribute to control "create folder" access right.
So is it possible to disable/control TFS user (on-premises) to create new Folder under TFS project? What i want to achieve is maintain the Project structure within the development team.

Comment: Hi @Martin, How are thing going? Have you tried as the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it, and any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to control permissions of the user to create folders on the TFVC repository?

We have no the special permission option for folder creation. Generally the users who have the "**`Check in`**" permission can add, edit and delete folders and files on the TFVC repository.

In your case, you can set "**`Check in`**" permission as '**`Deny`**' for the users on the TFVC repository level.

Then create the folders for the users to store the source code, and you can set the "**`Check in`**" permission as '**`Allow`**' for the users on the folder level.

In this way, normally the user can't create, edit and delete folders and files on the TFVC repository, but can create, edit and delete folders and files in the allowed folders.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It works but only for particular folder. If there are many project/folders, it is not a feasible solution. I wish there is folder creation permission in order to protect the TFS structure without closely monitor